# when substring is found, create a DOM element -php

Tags: php, dom, preg-match, preg-split

i want to split a string with regex, then create a dom element where i found the match, and do that till string ends.
given a string;

```
$str="hi there! [1], how are you? [2]";
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
<sentence>
hi there! <child1>1</child1>, how are you? <child2>2</child2>
</sentence>
```

i am using `php dom -> $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); ...`

to create root; (this might not have anything to do, but some people complains about no-effort and stuff..)

```
        $root= $dom->createElement('sentence', null);
        $root= $dom->appendChild($root);
        $root->setAttribute('attr-1', 'value-1');
```

i used several approaches like, and some with `preg-split`;

```
$counter=1;
$pos = preg_match('/\[([1-9][0-9]*)\]/', $str);
    if ($pos == true) {
    $substr=$dom->createElement('child', $counter);
    $root->appendChild($substr);
    $counter++;
    }
```

i know that code is not worthy, but again to show it is not a treat..

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code is not that far of. However you need to make the regular expression match as well the text you want to add (and you need a textnode for that). After each match you need to advance the offset as well, where to continue to match:

```
$str = "hi there! [1], how are you? [2]";

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$root= $dom->createElement('sentence', null);
$root= $dom->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttribute('attr-1', 'value-1'); # ...

$counter = 0;
$offset = 0;
while ($pos = preg_match('/(.*?)\[([1-9][0-9]*)\]/', $str, $matches, NULL, $offset)) {
    list(, $text, $number) = $matches;
    if (strlen($text)) {
        $root->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($text));
    }
    if (strlen($number)) {
        $counter++;
        $root->appendChild($dom->createElement("child$counter", $number));

    }
    $offset += strlen($matches[0]);
}
```

The `while` loop is comparable to the `if` you had, just turning it into a loop. Also the textnodes are added if there is some text matched (e.g. you could have [1][2] in your string so the text would be empty. Output of this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sentence attr-1="value-1">
  hi there! <child1>1</child1>, how are you? <child2>2</child2>
</sentence>
```

---

**Edit** After playing with this a bit I came to the conclusion that you might want to divide the problem. One part is to parse the string, and the other part is to actually insert nodes (e.g. textnode on text and elementnode if it's the number). Starting from behind, this immediately looks practical, second part first:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$root = $dom->createElement('sentence', null);
$root = $dom->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttribute('attr-1', 'value-1'); # ...

$str = "hi there! [1], how are you? [2] test";

$it = new Tokenizer($str);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($it as $type => $string) {
    switch ($type) {
        case Tokenizer::TEXT:
            $root->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($string));
            break;

        case Tokenizer::NUMBER:
            $counter++;
            $root->appendChild($dom->createElement("child$counter", $string));
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid type %s.', $type));
    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

In this example, we don't care about the parsing at all. We either get a text or a number (`$type`) and we can decide upon it to either insert the textnode or the element. So however the parsing of the string is done, this code will always work. If there is an issue with it (e.g. the `$counter` is not interesting any longer), it would have nothing to do with the parsing/tokenization of the string.

The parsing itself has been encapsulated into an `Iterator` called `Tokenizer`. It contains everything to break the string apart into text and number elements. It deals with all the details like what happens if there is some text after the last number and so on:

```
class Tokenizer implements Iterator
{
    const TEXT = 1;
    const NUMBER = 2;
    private $offset;
    private $string;
    private $fetched;

    public function __construct($string)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->offset = 0;
        $this->fetch();
    }

    private function fetch()
    {
        if ($this->offset >= strlen($this->string)) {
            return;
        }
        $result = preg_match('/\[([1-9][0-9]*)\]/', $this->string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $this->offset);
        if (!$result) {
            $this->fetched[] = array(self::TEXT, substr($this->string, $this->offset));
            $this->offset = strlen($this->string);
            return;
        }
        $pos = $matches[0][1];
        if ($pos != $this->offset) {
            $this->fetched[] = array(self::TEXT, substr($this->string, $this->offset, $pos - $this->offset));
        }
        $this->fetched[] = array(self::NUMBER, $matches[1][0]);
        $this->offset = $pos + strlen($matches[0][0]);
    }

    public function current()
    {
        list(, $current) = current($this->fetched);
        return $current;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        list($key) = current($this->fetched);
        return $key;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        array_shift($this->fetched);
        if (!$this->fetched) $this->fetch();
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return (bool)$this->fetched;
    }
}
```

That done has split the two problems apart from each other. Instead of an iterator class it is possible as well to create an array of arrays or similar, but I found the iterator more useful so I quickly wrote one.

Again this example outputs the XML at the end, so here it is exemplary. Note that I've added some text after the last element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sentence attr-1="value-1">
  hi there! <child1>1</child1>, how are you? <child2>2</child2> test
</sentence>
```

Comment: thanks hakre, i am trying to implement your solution right now. will post outcome in a bit..

Comment: i am still missing something,:( will post.

Comment: @teurara: It's not very stable, I edited the answer which might be helpful: Divide the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Perform the replacement with regular expressions first, then parse the document.

```
$xml = preg_replace('/\[(\d+)\]/', '<child$1>$1</child$1>', $str);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->loadXML("<sentence>$xml</sentence>");
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/6bGrqc8X)

Comment: thank you, but this won't help because i will be parsing the xml created afterwards. i won't be able to get <child> s..

Comment: @teutara: I'm sorry, could you please rephrase that?

Comment: i mean, since data is coming from a db and there are lots elements  created, at the same level or upper and so on, having child as string won' help

Comment: @teutara: It's not as a string, it's an XML document. Do you mean you want the elements to be called `<child>`, not `<child1>`, `<child2>`, etc.? Because that's what's in your example output.

Comment: you inspired me, just pardon me for 5 minutes to implement some code. will post the outcome..

Comment: i could not append this to root element, can you think of anything?

Comment: @teutara: I have no idea because you haven't shown your code. Believe me, this *already works* to parse a DOM document; everything you need will be in there.